# How to handle transactions spanning multiple threads with Spring Data and Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-data, spring-kafka

I'm working on an application which uses Kafka to consume messages from multiple topics, persisting data as it goes.

To that end I use a @Service class, with a couple of methods annotated with @kafkaListener. Consider this:

```
@Transactional
@KafkaListener(topics = MyFirstMessage.TOPIC, autoStartup = "false", containerFactory = "myFirstKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void handleMyFirstMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, MyFirstMessage> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) throws Exception {
    MyFirstMessage message = consume(record, acknowledgment);
    try {
        doHandle(record.key(), message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        TransactionInterceptor.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
    } finally {
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    }
}

@Transactional
@KafkaListener(topics = MySecondMessage.TOPIC, autoStartup = "false", containerFactory = "mySecondKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void handleMySecondMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, MySecondMessage> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) throws Exception {
    MySecondMessage message = consume(record, acknowledgment);
    try {
        doHandle(record.key(), message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        TransactionInterceptor.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
    } finally {
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    }
}
```

Please disregard the stuff about setRollbackOnly, it's not relevant to this question.

What IS relevant is that the doHandle() methods in each listener perform inserts in a table, which occasionally fail because autogenerated keys turn out to be non-unique once the final commit is done.

What happens is that each doHandle() method will increment the key column in their own little transactions, and only one of them will "win" that race. The other will fail during commit, with a non-unique constraint violation.

What is best practice to handle this? How do I "synchronize" transactions to execute like pearls on a string in stead of all at once?

I'm thinking of using some kind of semaphor or lock, to serialize things but that smells like a solution with many pitfalls. If there was a general pattern or framework to help with this problem I would be much more comfortable implementing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions).

Using `@Transactional` for the DB and a `KafkaTransactionManager` in the listener container is similar to using a `ChainedKafkaTransactionManager` (configured with both TMs) in the container. The DB tx is committed, followed by Kafka, when the listener exits normall.

When the listener throws an exception, both transactions are rolled back in the same order.

The `setRollbackOnly` is definitely relevant to this question since you are not rolling back the kafka transaction when you do that.

Comment: Hi Gary, I was hoping you might notice this question :-) Thanks for the feedback but I think we are not talking about the same things here. The two annotated methods are invoked simultaneously (by consumers in multiple threads I'm guessing), which causes two transactions to start, which in turn causes one of them to fail at the end when the commit occurs. If spring would invoke the listener methods one at a time this would not happen.

Comment: Regarding the setRollback stuff, this is intentional. The exception is fully "handled" if you will, by rolling back the DB tx (no Kafka retry or anything like that). We issue an ack to Kafka in the finally block, to indicate we want to proceed to the next message.

Comment: Sorry for the disconnect; my suggestion was to let the second one fail and roll back so it is redelivered. No; the two containers are independent and run on separate threads, so Spring can't invoke both listeners on one thread with that configuraiton. One option would be to use a single method to receive the raw data (`ByteArrayDeserializer`) and subscribe to both topics, then convert to the `My*Message` objects within the method. You'd only get one thread that way.

Comment: I was thinking along those lines as well, but it doesn't seem optimal at all. But if I let the DataIntegrityViolationException propagate out of the listener then the db tx will roll back and the entire operation will restart. And since my unique constraint won't be violated the second time around, this means it will go through on the first retry - and solve my problem. Which is something along the lines of what you suggested, so I'm going to accept that answer. Thanks again for always helping out here in Stackoverflow Gary - much appreciated.